# Why can't I download the latest Boot Camp installer when first configuring Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a white Macbook that is released near the end of 2007, with an Intel Core 2 Duo.  And now that I want to try installing Windows XP or Windows 7 on it to see how robust it is running Windows, with Boot Camp Assistant, it tried to "download files needed" but it always says "The Windows Support Software is not available"

[image]

without any further info. This Macbook is running Snow Leopard already. Is there a way to complete the process of installing Windows 7 using Boot Camp?

Comment: Let us know if you're still having this problem. You've got several good candidates for an answer here and it's not clear you even have this issue anymore. I'll close this off to new answers (but it'll still be searchable for others so they know to ask a follow on question if the answers here don't help them in their situation.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the option "I have already downloaded..." this will let you continue with the Boot Camp partitions and then install Windows from the disc.

You should install Boot Camp within Windows from your Snow Leopard Install CD and then you can update Boot Camp by downloading the Updates from support.apple.com.

I had this issue with my Mid-2010 MacBook Pro at first.

Comment: I am seeing this "should" and that "should", almost as if "Apple should not let you download the right support files, but you should this, and you should that, and they should work"

Comment: http://www.fixkb.com/2012/11/issues-with-boot-camp-assistant-mac-osx-10-5-10-6.html

Comment: @動靜能量: I think you’re over-analysing the word “should”.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that Apple dropped support for Boot Camp downloads under Snow Leopard.

My advice is to upgrade to Mountain Lion (or install it in a external drive) and try to download the Bootcamp-provided Windows Drivers from Mountain Lion's Boot Camp Assistant.